# PHP: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'http' (T_STRING) in

Tags: php

Without getting into too much details on my project, I'm currently trying to use PHP to download a remote file and store it in the current directory on the server. Please keep in mind I do not know much of anything about PHP and am trying to learn.

I'm using the following code:

```
<?php file_get_contents(''http://xxx.xx.xx/file.php/'');?>
```

As you can see, this is pretty basic, and I'm not even really sure if it will get the job done.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `('http://xxx.xx.xx/file.php/')`

Comment: You need to use double quotes not "double quotes".  `"` is one character, a double quote.  `''` is two characters, 2 single quotes.

Comment: You may have some issues with having access to the file also. Just because the functionality exists, doesn't mean you will be able to get to them.

Comment: P.S. You *cannot* download the PHP source file from another website.  This will *run* the PHP file (just like if you had done so in your browser) and return you the output (eg. an HTML page).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php file_get_contents("http://xxx.xx.xx/file.php");?>
```